# Want to check values are present or not in file

Tags: c, file

Here I have one file which contains some information, and I want to check some values of tags are present or not in file.If present, then I want to retrieve these values.

Here number of tags is fixed and lenght of tag would not be more than 16 and length of value of tag is almost fix it would not more than 10 bytes.

From below file I want to check `KERNEL` tag value is present or not,`FS` tag value is present or not, etc etc.

I want to check all values are present or not after `:` (colon).

My file contains text like this.

```
KERNEL:2.31
FS:3.4
XLOADER:1.1
UBOOT:2.2
```

or like this

```
KERNEL:2.31
FS:
XLOADER:1.3
UBOOT:
```

I am using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *infile = fopen("example.txt", "r");

    char buffer[256];
    char value[128];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), infile))
        if (1 == sscanf(buffer, "KERNEL:%s", value)) {
            printf("Value = %s\n", value);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

but in code i have to call 4 this function 4 times for different different values. like KERNEL,FS, etc.

this code output like this

```
Value = 2.31
```

i read line from the data file and than i want to parse value of every tag (Means wants to identify values is present or not).

So this is Good way to do this thing can any body suggest me ?

Comment: "At Stack Exchange, we insist that people who ask questions put some effort into their question, and we're kind of jerks about it."  (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not make it clear what context the file is in (or did not when I started answering).  Presumably, it is a text file that the application can find by some means.

You've not specified whether the contents (tags) are supposed to be fixed, whether the file can contain other information, whether there's a comment convention in place, whether blank lines are allowed, what happens if a tag is missing altogether, what happens if there's an unexpected tag in the file, what happens if a tag is repeated (with the same version, with a different version).  Are the tags case-sensitive; are leading blanks allowed before the tag; before the version; after the version?  What characters are allowed in the version number?  These are details that matter.

Let's assume that the list of names is fixed.  Let's assume that tags are not longer than 7 (8 with terminal null).  Let's assume that version numbers are not longer than 15 characters in total (16 allowing for terminal null).  Let's assume that you need to keep a record of which tags you found and the version that you found.

In that case, you will end up with a data structure a bit like this:

```
typedef struct VersionInfo
{
    char     tag[8];
    char     version[16];
} VersionInfo;

static VersionInfo version_data[] =
{
    { "KERNEL",  "" },
    { "FS",      "" },
    { "XLOADER", "" },
    { "UBOOT",   "" },
};
```

Clearly, with that basic structure available, you can write a function to read each line from the data file, discarding any comment or blank lines (if that's appropriate).  You can probably use `fgets()` for this; the expected lines are short.  You should probably complain about long lines, and decide whether to ignore them or stop processing.  You can look for each of the tags in the `version_data` array, and when you find one, note whether it has been found before or not, and then find the version information on the line and copy it into the corresponding part of the `version_data` array.

You might extend the structure with an 'expected version' field as well as the actual version field.  This will allow you to decide what to do based on the versions you find.  You might have ranges related the allowable versions, based on what was known when the program was compiled, for example.  You might allow the program that was compiled with 3.0.3 of something to run with 3.0.4 and later, and maybe you're even willing to work with 3.0.0 and later, but not any version 2.

Note that version comparison is a fine art in its own right.  For example, the versions 3.0.3, 3.1.2, 3.6, 3.6.1, 3.6.1.2, and 3.10.0 should probably be treated as being in ascending order of version number.  Using `strcmp()` won't achieve that (it will place `3.10.0` ahead of all the `3.6` versions).

---

I see that your example code uses `sscanf()` with a fixed string.  That probably ties you to a fixed order and certainly not as flexible as the data structure allows you to be.  If using `sscanf()`, I've be expecting to use a format such as:

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%7s:%15s", tag, version) != 2)
    ...something up with the input line...
...process tag and version that you did find...
```

You can refine the scans with the character class notations:

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%7[A-Z]:%15[0-9.]", tag, version) != 2)
```

This only accepts upper-case letters in the tag and only accepts digits and dots in the version information (but is quite happy with version "..0...0...0" which you probably shouldn't accept as valid).

Comment: Here but how can i fill data of KERNEL value to Structure. My first goal is that i want to check values are present or blank. If blank than i have to do nothing if present than leave it and proceed ahead. i will parse this file at receiver side. no need to parse here.

Comment: From line i want retrieve values of particular tag than my above code is file for that?

Comment: If you don't want to keep the information you read, don't copy it into the structure.  Indeed, you can simplify the structure to a simple list of tags that are expected.  You can even place them in the order that you expect them to appear.  The possibilities are endless.  It isn't clear why you'd want to read the file and check whether there's a value present or not if you don't record somehow that the value is present or absent.  Since the motivation for this checking is presently inscrutable (or, at least, unscruted by me), it is hard to give a really good answer about what to do.

Comment: Here for sender side i want to check these values are present or not and receiver side i will parse them and put things in structure. so i can read from there.

Comment: Please Can u join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9033/some-imp-chat

Answer (score 0):

Given your samples, the first approach I'd try is:

```
Read a line
Remove all whitespace
   If the last character on the line is a colon <do something>
Else
    Do something else
```